# Permission on multiple routes in a custom API for an Azure mobile service

Tags: api, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am working in Azure Mobile Service where I have made a custom api. For those it is possible to set permissions (like public, application, user and admin), which is very useful. But I need multi-level api (like for example `/api/user/profile/{userId}`), and to be able to set some permission to the sub-level api.

I have found it is possible to add other levels of api paths with the following code

```
exports.register = function (api) {

    /* Get public user profile on some other user */
    api.get('/profile/:userId', getProfileFunc);

    /* Get private profile only for the authenticated user */
    api.get('/profile', getProvateProfileFunc);

    /* Update provate profile only for the authenticated user */
    api.put('/profile', updateProfileFunc);
}

exports.get = getUserListFunc;
```

The api permissions are set through the {api-name}.json-file for the top level.
But how can I set a permission to a sub-level api *that is different* from the parent api? An illustration:
GET: api/user gets a list of users and is permission *application*
GET: api/user/profile gets the profile for (the authenticated) user, and therefor needs permission *user*.

And the permissions in *user.json* are

```
{
  "routes": {
    "*": {
      "get": {"permission": "application"},
      "post": {"permission": "admin"},
      "put": {"permission": "admin"},
      "patch": {"permission": "admin"},
      "delete": {"permission": "admin"}
    }
  }
}
```

I an working with a git repository connected to my WAMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .json file supports routes. Try the following:

```
{
    "routes": {          
        "/" : { "permission": "public" },
        "/user/profile/:userId" : {
            "get": { "permission": "public" },
            "post": { "permission": "authenticated" }
        }
    }
}
```